# Beautiful Soup 4 for python 3

Tags: python, parsing, web, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Does anyone know where I could find a video tutorial on the use of python 3 with Beautifulsoup 4?  I really need to know how to use it so that I can write a script with it.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have a specific question that isn't addressed in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)?

Comment: Not particularly.  I just need to know how to sort through stock data and collect certain figures like price and 52 week highs/lows.  I tried watching some of the youtube tutorials, but none of the code works with python 3 and BS4.

Answer (score 3):

Chris Hawkes at [noobniche](http://www.noobniche.com/) has a couple of BeautifulSoup video tutorials.  They are episodes [7](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=keefYknSbt4) and [8](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i9G6SJLtFm0).

Another example, also found at youtube, covers using BeautifulSoup to work with weather forecast data.  It can be viewed [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mZ3R8M-8Mk).

Comment: Thanks for your response, but these do not work with python 3 and Bs4.  Do you know where I could get some info about how to use Bs4 with python 3?